# How do i programmatically write to *standard-input* for evaluation at the repl?

Tags: common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I type the following in a repl (clozure common lisp)

```
(defparameter test 1)
```

The repl responds with  `test`

Now I enter:

```
(format *standard-input* "(defparameter test 2)")
```

Repl outputs `(defparameter test 2)` followed by `nil`.

But the value of test remains unchanged at 1.

**Why is this? Isn't writing to the variable `*standard-input*` the same as entering the text at the repl?**

*How do I achieve the desired evaluation?*

---

Some context:

I'm making a custom frontend for common lisp development using sockets. I need to write to standard input because even though I can evaluate code using eval and read, I cannot debug the code on errors.

For instance entering 1 to unwind the stack and return to top level is impossible without writing to standard input (as far as I can tell). I have the output parts figured out.

Comment: "entering 1…" don't you want to catch and handle errors programmatically instead?

Comment: Not really, that would be easily done with handler-bind etc. The front-end I'm developing is browser based that communicates with a running repl in a terminal via websockets. The code to be evaluated is sent over the websocket connection, read and evaluated by the repl and the results are sent back over the same connection. It all works nicely. Except when there is an error. Now I would like to send the *debug-io* output to the browser, which works, but when I send say a "1" or other expected input, I can no longer evaluate it you see? If I do, its still just a 1, it doesn't get processed.

Answer (score 2):

`*standard-input*` is an *input* stream, as its name implies.  It's a stream you read from, not one you write to.  It may be an output stream as well, but if it is then writing to it is not going to inject strings into the REPL.

I'd suggest looking at [SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) or [SLY](https://github.com/joaotavora/sly) if you want to understand how to have REPLs & debuggers which interact with things down streams.  In particular [SWANK](https://www.cliki.net/SWANK) is probably the interesting bit to understand, or the equivalent for SLY, which is SLYNK (or slynk, not sure of the capitalisation).  The implementations of these protocols in various Lisps are not entirely trivial, but *the implementations exist already*: you don't have to write them.  Screen-scraping an interface made for humans to interact with is almost always a terrible approach: it's only reasonable when there is no better way, and in this case there is a better way, in fact there are at least two.